# prove that: $(a^2+1)(a^2+b^2+1)(a^2+b^2+c^2+1)\ge16abc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a,b,c\ge0$, prove that: $$(a^2+1)(a^2+b^2+1)(a^2+b^2+c^2+1)\ge16abc$$

I tried AM-GM as below:

$$a^2+1\ge2a; a^2+b^2\ge2ab; a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$$ The rest is proving the inequality which is not true for all non-negative real numbers: $a(2ab+1)(ab+bc+ca+1)\ge8abc$

By the way, equality do not hold for a=b=c, so I guess my approach seems lost. Is there any better idea to help me deal with problem? Thank you!

Comment: it's a quadratic in $c$, so find the discriminant and show that it is non-positive.

Comment: Can you tell more help me?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h2711511_noncyclic_inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write it as a quadratic in $c$ and find its discriminant, then it suffices to prove:
$$(a^2+1)^2(a^2+b^2+1)^3\geq 64a^2b^2.$$
This can be done with AM-GM since:
$$(a^2+1)^2 = \left(a^2+\frac 13+\frac 13+\frac 13\right)^2\geq (4\cdot3^{- 3/4}a^{ 1/2})^2=\dfrac{16}{3\sqrt{3}}a$$
and so
$$(a^2+b^2+1)^3 = \left(b^2+\dfrac{a^2+1}{2}+\dfrac{a^2+1}{2}\right)^3\geq \dfrac{27}{4}b^2(a^2+1)^2\geq12\sqrt{3}b^2a$$
and when you multiply them together, we obtain the desired. The equality is reached at:
$$b = \sqrt{2}a = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$$
and from this you can deduce when is your original inequality is attained.

**EDIT:**

If one insists on using purely AM-GM, then:
$$c^2+a^2+b^2+1\geq 2c\sqrt{a^2+b^2+1}$$  and therefore:
$$(a^2+1)(a^2+b^2+1)(a^2+b^2+c^2+1)\geq 2c(a^2+1)\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+1)^3}\geq$$
$$\geq 2c(a^2+1)\dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}b(a^2+1)=3\sqrt{3}bc(a^2+1)^2\geq 3\sqrt{3}bc\cdot\dfrac{16}{3\sqrt{3}}a=16abc.$$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I made a typo in the last sentence. Should give $c = \sqrt{2}.$

Comment: Now I get it, thank you very much!